# Lebesgue integral of $\sin(x+y)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I have been attempting to calculate the following Lebesgue integral, but I'm not very confident that my method is correct, so I would appreciate it if someone could take a look and let me know if this is right.
$$
\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]\times[0,\pi]}\sin{(x+y)}\hspace{1mm} dm(x,y)
$$

We begin by showing that the following integral is finite:
$$
\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]\times[0,\pi]}|\sin{(x+y)}|\hspace{1mm} dm(x,y)
$$

But $\sin{(x+y)} \leq 1$ so by monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]\times[0,\pi]}|\sin{(x+y)}|\hspace{1mm} dm(x,y)
& \le \int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]\times[0,\pi]}1\hspace{1mm} dm(x,y) \\
& = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}1\hspace{1mm} dy dx
=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi} \pi \hspace{1mm} dx
= \frac{3\pi^{2}}{2}
< \infty
\end{align*}

So we can calculate our integral as an iterated integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]\times[0,\pi]}\sin{(x+y)}\hspace{1mm} dm(x,y)
& =\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]}\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin{(x+y)}\hspace{1mm} dm(y)dm(x) \\
& =\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]}[-\cos(x+y)]^{\pi}_{0}\hspace{1mm} dm(x) \\
& =\int_{[-\pi/2,\pi]}[\cos(x)-\cos(x+\pi)]\hspace{1mm} dm(x) \\
& = [\sin(x)-\sin(x+\pi)]^{\pi}_{-\pi/2}
=2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your end result [is correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin+(x+%2B+y)+dx+dy,+x%3D-pi%2F2..pi,+y%3D0..pi). What part of the calculation makes you doubt yourself?

Comment: Well, you calculated the integral of $sin(x+y)$ but you didn't calculate it according to the definition of Lebesgue integral. Do you know it?

Comment: @Hume2 On our course we have been taught to calculate the integral in the same way as a Riemann integral in the cases where the two coincide. I know the theory of the Lebesgue integral, although I'm not sure how I would calculate it in this case without using the standard integration rules.

Comment: @TomSmith The last three lines are Newton integral. Was the assignment only to calculate any integral or were you told to calculate it according to any definition?

Comment: @Hume2 the question just asked to evaluate the integral. The last few lines followed from the Fubini-Tonelli theorem that we were taught in the course, where you can "split" the integral provided the integral of the modulus of the function is finite.

Comment: @TomSmith Then yes, you are correct. When a function has two or more integrals, they are all the same. So you didn't have to write that you are calculating Lebesgue integral if you could do enough by any other integral, that confused me.

Comment: @Hume2 apologies. The course is called Lebesgue integration which is why I wrote that. How would you calculate this integral just from the definition of the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @TomSmith Firstly, I'd need to decompose the function to the positive part and the negative part and evaluate each part extra. Then I'd need to approximate the function by a simple function and calculate the area bellow it. I'm not quite sure how I'd do this step. And after that, I'd substract the integrals of both parts.

Comment: @Hume2 OK thanks. That is indeed the method that I was aware of, but I think I'm OK to use simpler methods of integration when they're available.